# Unmet Peer Dependency react-native@0.40.0

Tags: react-native

I'm using `npm install react-native@0.40.0 --save` to upgrade React Native, but I keep getting an error that I have an "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-native@0.40.0".

This confuses me because I thought I had just installed react-native@0.40.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those error messages can be really poorly worded. I've seen this same thing; it's reporting that you have `react-native@0.40.0` installed, but something else is requesting a *different* version.

I'd suggest doing an `npm ls`; it will give you a better picture of all the peer dependency requirements and what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried `npm ls`, and it appears that I have two conflicting requirements: one for `react-native@^0.33.0` and another for `react-native@>=0.40`. Is there any way this can be resolved?

Comment: Ouch. Unfortunately, I don't think you have a good way to resolve that short of finding dependencies that have compatible `react-native` dependencies.